# Meter breaker box disconnect box

Tags: electrical

Can I run 2/0 wire from my meter to the barn to 200 amp breaker box then go below and add 200 amp disconnect box and then hook into disconnect box and run to my breaker box on my little house

Comment: Will ALL the current for the entire service come through those wires? Or will it be forked off at the meter to different buildings?

Comment: Is there a disconnect at the meter?  Is the meter on a pole, or on the barn, for that matter? Can you post photos of the equipment involved?  How much distance is there between the meter, the barn, and the house site? Is the breaker box on the barn an existing box, and if so, what make and model is it?

Comment: The meter is on the side of house I want to come off it with 2/0 wire and run it to barn where I have brand new 200 amp breaker box then go below that breaker box and add a disconect box and run from it to a little house with a 200 amp breaker box not sure on brand of boxes

Comment: The breaker box at barn is a main breaker box

Comment: The box is a Cutler hammer

Comment: From meter to  main breaker is 120 ft. From disconect to little house is 75ft

Comment: Will the run to the barn have a circuit breaker in front of it, or will it be hotshot straight off the meter?

Comment: It will be straight out of meter to barn hooked to main breaker box with a disconect at bottom of that main breaker box

Comment: Meter is on side of house

Comment: But I want to come off of the disconect box and go to a 800 sq ft. House to its breaker box

Comment: How many amps of service are coming into the main house?

Comment: Im. Just going to run a whole new service with a meter